# CSS background image transition - slide instead of fade

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have the following HTML to create the markup for a CSS slideshow:

```css
/* SLIDESHOW STYLES */

.slideshow,
.slideshow:after {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.slideshow:after {
  content: '';
}

.slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
}


/* Set images */

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url("//placekitten.com/100");
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url("//placekitten.com/200");
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url("//placekititen.com/150");
  animation-delay: 12s;
}


/* Animation for the slideshow images */

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="slideshow">
  <li><span></span>
    <div>
      <h3>Dummy text 1</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span></span>
    <div>
      <h3>Dummy text 2</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span></span>
    <div>
      <h3>Dummy text 3</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This code will fade one background image in after another and loop. What I want to do is change the transition from a fade to a slide in from the right shifting the other to the left. Obviously the first image that loads should have NO transition.

Please advise

Comment: see: https://unused-css.com/blog/css-only-background-slider/#slider-generator

Comment: "Obviously the first image that loads should have NO transition." or maybe not so obvious without mind reading

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a slideshow:

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 2500);    
}
```

```css
.mySlides img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<ul class="slideshow">
  <li class="mySlides w3-animate-right"><span><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" alt="first"></span>
    <div>
      <h3>Dummy text 1</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="mySlides w3-animate-right"><span><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" alt="second"></span>
    <div>
      <h3>Dummy text 2</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="mySlides w3-animate-right"><span><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3" alt="third"></span>
    <div>
      <h3>Dummy text 3</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For more info: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

Answer (score 0):

CSS only no JavaScript;

Credit where credit is due got lot of ideas from https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/.  See this for how the navigation works.  Style as you please.

Images I put some as background from CSS and last one as "content" in the HTML with some text as examples.

Remove the left/right arrow navigation if you want, remove the navigation at the bottom if you wish also.

```css
/* NEW STUFF */
@keyframes tonext {
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  98% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes tostart {
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  98% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes snap {
  96% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
  97% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  99% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  100% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
}

body {
  max-width: 37.5rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scrollbar-color: transparent transparent; /* thumb and track color */
  scrollbar-width: 0px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

* {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

ol, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 75%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #0003);
  perspective: 100px;
}

.carousel__viewport {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  counter-reset: item;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.carousel__slide {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff999940;
  counter-increment: item;
}

.carousel__slide:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #9999ff40;
}
/* put counters as content in with CSS 
.carousel__slide:before {
  content: counter(item);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-40%,70px);
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 2em;
}
*/

.carousel__slide {
  /* super centers content on the slide*/

  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
}
.carousel__slide .slide-content{
/* super centers text on slide */
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  color:#FF0000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-child(1) .slide-content{
  background-image: url("//placekitten.com/100");
}
.carousel__slide:nth-child(2) .slide-content{
  background-image: url("//placekitten.com/200");
}
.carousel__slide:nth-child(3) .slide-content{
  background-image: url("//placekitten.com/150");
}

.carousel__snapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tonext, snap;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }

  .carousel__slide:last-child .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tostart, snap;
  }
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: none;
  }
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__snapper,
.carousel:focus-within .carousel__snapper {
  animation-name: none;
}

.carousel__navigation {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel__navigation-list,
.carousel__navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.carousel__navigation-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #33333340;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 0.25rem solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel::after,
.carousel__prev,
.carousel__next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 37.5%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel__prev {
  left: -1rem;
}

.carousel::after,
.carousel__next {
  right: -1rem;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #00ff4080;
  background-size: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.carousel::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,50 80,100 80,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='100,50 20,100 20,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<section class="carousel" aria-label="Gallery">
  <ol class="carousel__viewport">
    <li id="carousel__slide1"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
        <div class="slide-content">cheese bits</div>
        <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
        <a href="#carousel__slide4"
           class="carousel__prev">Go to last slide</a>
        <a href="#carousel__slide2"
           class="carousel__next">Go to next slide</a>
    </li>
    <li id="carousel__slide2"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
        <div class="slide-content">black bread</div>
      <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
      <a href="#carousel__slide1"
         class="carousel__prev">Go to previous slide</a>
      <a href="#carousel__slide3"
         class="carousel__next">Go to next slide</a>
    </li>
    <li id="carousel__slide3"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="slide-content">steak - chared</div>
      <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
      <a href="#carousel__slide2"
         class="carousel__prev">Go to previous slide</a>
      <a href="#carousel__slide4"
         class="carousel__next">Go to next slide</a>
    </li>
    <li id="carousel__slide4"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="slide-content"><img src="//placekitten.com/300"/>Last of my kind</div>
      <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
      <a href="#carousel__slide3"
         class="carousel__prev">Go to previous slide</a>
      <a href="#carousel__slide1"
         class="carousel__next">Go to first slide</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <aside class="carousel__navigation">
    <ol class="carousel__navigation-list">
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide1"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide2"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide3"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide4"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 4</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </aside>
</section>
```